# Converting Gauss-Krueger to Lon/Lat in R

Tags: coordinate-system, r

I have sets of Gauss-Krueger coordinates (zone 3) that I'd like to transform to longitude and latitude in R. Here's an example:

```
library(sp)
coord_gk <- data.frame(GK_R = c(4555277),
                       GK_H = c(5342348))

coordinates(coord_gk) <- c("GK_R", "GK_H")
proj4string(coord_gk) <- CRS("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=krass +units=m +no_defs")
coord_lonlat <- spTransform(coord_gk, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

> coord_lonlat
SpatialPoints:
         GK_R     GK_H
[1,] 28.97989 47.35438
```

However, the output is not correct. I expect it to be 12.742421, 48.216707.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be Zone 4 rather than Zone 3. If I do:

```
> proj4string(coord_gk) <- CRS("+init=epsg:31468")
```

I get:

```
> spTransform(coord_gk,CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
SpatialPoints:
        GK_R    GK_H
[1,] 12.7424 48.2167
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +init=epsg:4326
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

which is bang on.

http://epsg.io/31468 if you want the parameters.

Comment: YES! I hadn't questioned the zone at all. Thanks!